# Determine whether the $\sum\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}$ is convergent or divergent.

Tags: calculus, analysis

I know that $\sum(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$ is divergent by doing the Telescoping Series.

Now our given series is, $\sum\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}$. I considered doing the Ratio Test on the given series but did not go too well. It just gave me a much more complicated series to work with.

I was given a hint that I could use the Comparison Test and compare it with $\dfrac{1}{(\sqrt{n})^3}$. I'm confused as to why we would be comparing it to that?

Comment: Multiplying the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$, you get $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}n = \frac1{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})} \leq\frac1{2n\sqrt{n}}$. Does that help?

Comment: Ratio test always fail on non-rapidly converging series. Forget about it.